# XSLT 1.0 how to move string front and back

Tags: string, xslt

I'm still new to xslt and recently i got a request to change a xslt logic. So I'm here looking for help.

This is the input from external system.

```
<item>
    <OBJ_CODE>(01)04030539083706(21)81490930005891136867</OBJ_CODE>
</item>
<item>
    <OBJ_CODE>(01)04030539083706(21)81490930005891143208</OBJ_CODE>
</item>
```

and below is my expected result. so basically the requirement is to move the first 7 characters after (21) to the back and add fix value(A99), then move the last 13 characters to the front.

```
<SN>(01)04030539083706(21)0005891136867(A99)8149093</SN>
<SN>(01)04030539083706(21)0005891136867(A99)8149093</SN>
```

appreciate if anyone could help. please let me know if my description is not clear.

here is my current xslt mapping.

```
<xsl:template match="item">
        <SN>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../../EncodingType = 'SSCC'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(OBJ_CODE,1,23)"/><xsl:value-of select="substring(OBJ_CODE,30,13)"/>(A99)<xsl:value-of select="substring(OBJ_CODE,23,7)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="OBJ_CODE"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>
        </SN>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Should be quite easy using the substring functions - esp. if the length of the substring before `(21)` is constant. Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k hi. i was able to get the result with the following function.

<xsl:value-of select="substring(OBJ_CODE,30,13)"/>(A99)<xsl:value-of select="substring(OBJ_CODE,23,7)"/>
do u think it make sense to do this way ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your current XSLT there - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have added my current xlst.

Comment: i have further edited my xslt. it seems working but i dont know if it make sense or not. Or is there any other simplified way ?

Comment: No, 3 substring() instances is what it takes. You can make it more readable, though, by placing `(A99)` in `xsl:text` and indenting. And I don't see what `<xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>` does.

Comment: P.S. If you prefer, you can use `concat()` to cram everything into a single `xsl:value-of` instruction. But IMHO, it's better to keep them separate and make the code more readable.